# NSXMLParser Parsing Attributes

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, ios4

How do you extract attributes from XML using NSXML parser??

Heres my xml:

```
<item>
<title>Button hails 'amazing' win</title>
<description>Jenson Button hailed yesterday's crazy Canadian Grand Prix victory as the best of his Formula One career.
</description>
<link>http://www.skysports.com/story/0,19528,12433_6986809,00.html</link>
<guid isPermaLink="false">12433_6986809</guid>
<pubDate>Mon, 13 Jun 2011 06:21:00 GMT</pubDate>
<category>News Story</category>
<enclosure type="image/jpg" url="http://img.skysports.com/11/06/128x67/Canadian-GP-Jenson-Button-celebrates1_2609288.jpg" length="123456" />
</item>
```

I need to get the url from the enclosure tags.

Thanks

Answer (score 15, accepted):

```
if([elementName isEqualToString:@"enclosure"])
{
    NSString *urlValue=[attributeDict valueForKey:@"url"];
    NSString *urlValue=[attributeDict valueForKey:@"type"];
    NSString *urlValue=[attributeDict valueForKey:@"length"];
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer.

I would like to add that these lines should go to the delegate method of `NSXMLParser` which is:
`- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didStartElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qualifiedName attributes:(NSDictionary *)attributeDict`.

Comment: Made my day...Too simple..:)

Answer (score 3):

you need to use NSXMLParser and its delegate functions

-

```
 (BOOL) parse:(NSData *)xmlData 


-(void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didStartElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName attributes:(NSDictionary *)attributeDict{         



}

- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didEndElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName{   

}

- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser foundCharacters:(NSString *)string{

}
```

then you need to use some thing like this

```
if([elementName isEqualToString:@"enclosure"])
    {
        NSMutableDictionary *Dict=[NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
        [Dict setObject:[attributeDict valueForKey:@"url"] forKey:@"url"];
        [categoryDict setObject:[attributeDict valueForKey:@"type"] forKey:@"type"];

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

The method...

```
(void) parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didStartElement:(NSString *)elementName 
  namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI 
 qualifiedName:(NSString *)qualifiedName 
    attributes:(NSDictionary *)attributeDict
```

Gives you a dictionary of attributes and their keys (attributeDict)... look for an entry keyed "url" when the elementName is equal to "enclosure"...

Answer (score 0):

Here is explanation:
Example xml with attribute:

[image]

Use xml delegate method:

```
- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didStartElement:(NSString *)elementName 
namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName
attributes:(NSDictionary *)attributeDict
 {
    if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"remoteContent"]){
        NSString* href = [attributeDict objectForKey:@"href"];
        NSLog(@"href %@",href);
       [someArray addObject:href];
  }
}
```