# How to fetch data from the xml using objective c?

Tags: objective-c, ios4

I have the xml structure as follows

```
<xml_api_reply version="1">
    <weather module_id="0" tab_id="0" mobile_row="0" mobile_zipped="1" row="0" section="0">
    <forecast_information>
    <city data="Chennai, Tamil Nadu"/>
    <postal_code data="chennai"/>
    <forecast_date data="2011-12-13"/>
    <current_date_time data="1970-01-01 00:00:00 +0000"/>
    <unit_system data="US"/>
    </forecast_information>
    <current_conditions>
    <condition data="Haze"/>
    <temp_f data="84"/>
    <temp_c data="29"/>
    <humidity data="Humidity: 58%"/>
    <icon data="/ig/images/weather/haze.gif"/>
    <wind_condition data="Wind: NE at 13 mph"/>
    </current_conditions>
     </weather >
</xml_api_reply>
```

How to fetch this data and store it in an array?

Comment: Did you take a look at NSXMLParser?

Comment: Please provide enough information regarding the question. Are you trying to pull data from a server or read from Local file?

Comment: Exact duplicate of [How to fetch data with index from the xml using objective c?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8486902/how-to-fetch-data-with-index-from-the-xml-using-objective-c) - why post the same question again?

Answer (score 0):

Actually you are having the XML which is having Attributes.... Is is also very Easy. You can refer this [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6329143/nsxmlparser-parsing-attributes):-

Like

```
if([elementName isEqualToString:@"city"]) {

  NSString *urlValue=[attributeDict valueForKey:@"data"]; 
}
```

Hope This Helps You...:))
 and if not then tell me i will try to Help you more.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to use a framework like KissXML (https://github.com/robbiehanson/KissXML) to do the parsing of the XML for you.

```
DDXMLDocument *myXmlDoc = [DDXMLDocument alloc] initWithXMLString:myXmlString options:options error:nil];

NSArray *elements = [[myXmlDoc rootElement] elementsWithName:@"forecast_information"];
...
do stuff with the elements
```

For documentation on KissXML you can read Apple's docs on [NSXML](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSXMLDocument_Class/Reference/Reference.html), as KissXML is modeled after this